# Guardar el video de la webcam en el servidor en directo

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, nodejs

Quiero subir al servidor el vídeo que graba la webcam. Ahora lo que hago es grabar el vídeo y una vez se termina la grabación subirlo entero, para grabarlo uso RecordRTC, además de HTML5 y Javascript. Lo que quiero es subirlo mientras se está grabando.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo conseguir subir el vídeo y guardarlo en el servidor mientras se está grabando?

No quiero usar Flash.

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos el siguiente código javascript para grabar el video:

```
var fileType = 'video'; // or "audio"
var fileName = 'ABCDEF.webm';  // or "wav"

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

xhr('save.php', formData, function (fName) {
     window.open(location.href + fName);
});

function xhr(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(location.href + request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.send(data);
}
```

El script de destino `save.php` podría ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
    foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
        if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

            $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
            $uploadDirectory = DIR.'/uploads/'.$fileName;

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
                echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
            }

            echo($uploadDirectory);
        }
    }
?>
```

Puedes aprender más sobre ello [aquí](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP)

Comment: muchas gracias, esto es justo lo que hago actualmente. El problema es que lo que a mi me gustaría es que el vídeo se vaya subiendo mientras se está grabando, así nos evitamos la espera de tener que subir todo el vídeo junto.